# How to make two arrays from this json data?

Tags: javascript, html

My data is `animalCount: {Tiger: 3, Leopard: 6, Rat: 1}`

So I need to have 1st array

```
name :['Tiger', 'Leopard', 'Rat']
```

2nd array

```
count: [3, 6, 1]
```

Is it possible to obtain the same?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use:

```
 const names = Object.keys(animalCount);
 const values = Object.values(animalCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can use:

```
var name = Object.keys(animalCount);
var count = Object.values(animalCount);
```

If you, for some reason, needed to manipulate or change them while creating these arrays, you could also use a `for i in animalCount` loop, like so:

```
var animalCount = {Tiger: 3, Leopard: 6, Rat: 1};
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 = [];
        for(i in animalCount){
            if(animalCount.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                array1.push(i);
                array2.push(animalCount[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(array1);
        console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var name = [];
var count = [];
for(var prop in animalCount){
    name.push(prop);
    count.push(animalCount[prop]);
}
```

This way we're sure the order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

JS supports this natively.

```
var name = Object.keys(animalCount);
var count = Object.values(animalCount);
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for `Object.keys` and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values for `Object.values`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and reduce the entries of the object by iterating the key/value array for pushing the items.

```js
var animalCount = { Tiger: 3, Leopard: 6, Rat: 1 },
    names = [],
    count = [],
    result = Object
        .entries(animalCount)
        .reduce((r, a) => (a.forEach((v, i) => r[i].push(v)), r), [names, count]);

console.log(names);
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```